# How can make css animation from top?

Tags: css, animation

Guys i wanna animate from top? How can i do it?

```css
#box {
  width:50px;
  height:300px;
  background:#272822;
  position:relative;
  animation:box 1s linear infinite;
  top:0;
}
@keyframes box {
  from {height:200px;}
  to {height:250px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

ow can i do it?

Comment: That's what it does. No?

Comment: See it full page.It animates from bottom. @phenxd

Comment: "i wanna animate from top" is extremely ambiguous ...  If you were to be more descriptive about what you are attempting, you might yield more results ...

Comment: I see the black bar starting on top...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by animating margin-top rather than height.

```css
#box {
  width:50px;
  background:#272822;
  animation:box 1s linear infinite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
@keyframes box {
  from {height: 250px; margin-top: 10px;}
  to {height: 200px; margin-top: 60px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to start from the top (limit), change the 'from height' to 0...

```css
#box {
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  background:#272822;
  position:relative;
  animation:box 1s linear infinite;
  top:0;
}
@keyframes box {
  from {height:0px;}
  to {height:150px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```